# npx react-native run-android --variant=release fails but succeeds with ./gradlew bundleRelease?

Tags: react-native, npx

this is my error message which i don't know what to look for:

```
info Writing bundle output to:, /Users/glendonphilippbaculio/Desktop/rnAnimated2/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle
info Writing sourcemap output to:, /Users/glendonphilippbaculio/Desktop/rnAnimated2/android/app/build/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.packager.map
info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 123 asset files
info Done copying assets
<==-----------> 17% EXECUTING [1m 15s]
> :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
MaxBufferError: stderr maxBuffer exceeded
    at PassThrough.<anonymous> (/Users/glendonphilippbaculio/Desktop/rnAnimated2/node_modules/get-stream/index.js:41:19)
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:11)
    at PassThrough.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at PassThrough.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:152:32)
    at PassThrough.afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:96:10)
    at PassThrough._transform (_stream_passthrough.js:46:3)
    at PassThrough.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:191:10)
    at PassThrough.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:179:12)
```

everything seems fine on ./gradlew bundleRelease and also there's aab file, it just can't get through npx react-native run-android --variant=release :(

Comment: Do you remember how you fxed it?